# Error: variable (struct) has initializer but incomplete type (C)

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, compiler-errors, dynamic-memory-allocation

Okay, I'm very new to C and need an explanation as to why I'm getting this error:

"variable 'newFilm' has initializer but incomplete type"

The task is to create a struct called film. Then pass the data from a .txt file into that struct and create a linked list of structs representing all of the data in the .txt

The problem seems to be that the compiler is missing the point where I allocate memory for the struct newFilm which I believe is being done correctly

Code in main file:

```
char* t = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
int y;
char* r = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
char* g = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
int rt;
double s;

List* list = newList();

//read pReadFile
char input[256];
//read characters from file being pointed at, and store into input
    while( fgets( input, 256, pReadFile )) {
        //scan each line with each variable separated by a comma
        fscanf(pReadFile,"%s %d %s %s %d %d\n", t,y,r,g,rt,s);    
        struct Film newFilm = createFilm(t,y,r,g,rt,s); //ERROR OCCURS HERE
        addToList(list, newFilm); 
}

printList(list, pWriteFile);
```

Here is the createFilm function from film.c source file:

```
Film *createFilm(char *title, int year, char *rating,  
                  char *genre, int runtime, double score){

   Film *newFilm = (Film*)malloc(sizeof(Film));   
   // n.b. error checking to be added - to be added

    title = (char*)malloc(sizeof(title));
    newFilm->title = title;


    newFilm->year = year;

    rating = (char*)malloc(sizeof(rating));
    newFilm->rating = rating;

    genre = (char*)malloc(sizeof(genre));
    newFilm->genre = genre;


    newFilm->runtime = runtime;


    newFilm->score = score;



    return newFilm;
}
```

While I don't think there is anything wrong with the addToList function I thought I'd keep it so you have better context (in database.h file):

```
void addToList(List* list, struct Film* film){

    Node *node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    //Generates an error message and the program terminates if 
    //insufficient memory is available.
    if (node == NULL){

        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to allocate memory in list_add()\n");

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //appends film to tail of linked list
    node->film = film;
    node->next = NULL;

    if (list->last == NULL){
        list->first = list->last = node;
    }
    else{
        list->last = list->last->next = node;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: `Here is the createFilm function from film.h header file`...wait..what?

Comment: Sorry, not header file. got confused.

Comment: Let us assume the sizeof a pointer is 4.  `char* t = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));` is strange.  Why allocate for `t`, which points to a `char` array, 4 bytes?  If code needs an array of 100 `char`, use `char* t = malloc(100);`

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the declaration of the struct. With `struct Film;` you can create as many `struct Film *` pointers as you would like, because the compiler can figure out how big a pointer to a film will have to be (big enough to point to a struct).

However, since all you have is that Film is a struct (not what the struct is, or how big it is) you can't actually create a `struct Film` variable, since the compiler can't know how much space to allocate for that. There are two fixes for this:

1. Make the entire struct visible.

This likely involves moving the struct definition (not just declaration) to the header file. IE:

```
// old film.h
struct Film;

// new film.h
struct Film {
    int with;
    int all;
    int of;
    int the;
    int things;
    int it;
    int needs;
};
```

2. Make the entire struct opaque, and use opaque accesses.

This means that you never actually create `struct Film` anywhere in the code that uses it. Instead you write functions to create/destroy a film pointer and to access/modify each element.

Typically option 2 is more extensible (since changing the struct doesn't affect the code) but option 1 is easier.